# Master Page Loading Multiple Pages

Tags: asp.net

I'm developing a web site that has a master page that consists of 4 different pages that will load simultaneously (using ContentPlaceHolder).

However, when I test the website on my local machine, only one page renders at a time (depending on the URL I type in).

Is there any way that on Page Load, to tell the master (or maybe the browser?) to load all 4 pages instead of only the page that was directly requested from the browser?

Comment: This doesn't make sense.  How is the browser going to display four pages?  Do you want them to be in 4 different tabs?  If so, that's a client-side concern and would be done with JavaScript.  Explain the desired result a little more and show the code you're using so far to try to accomplish this.

Comment: Are you saying that your master page has 4 different content place holders and you want each one to load different content, that content each coming from different aspx pages?  Because that is not how master pages work.

Comment: I was thinking about using ContentPlaceHolder to grab the pages themselves, but misunderstood Master pages in general.  For some reason I got it into my head that the master page ContentPlaceHolder could house different .aspx pages, when now I know that they clearly can't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A master page doesn't work like a frameset that you display other pages in, you only display a single page using the frameset.

You can have several content placeholders in the master page, but all content still comes from the same page.

If you want to have the content in separate files, you should create user controls that you can include in a page.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you should be using iframes.  Context place holders are designed so that a single page can display its content against a common theme or background - the master page.

You can have multiple context place holders but they ALL must be populated by the page being loaded.  For instance, 1 master page could have a place holder for a menu and another for the content and a third for a news feed sidebar, but the aspx page using the master page has to define the content of all 3 place holders.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm not understanding, but add another page selecting "Web Form using Master Page" from the Add New Item dialog and then on the next window select your master page. Try navigating to the page you just added.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're misunderstanding master pages, the master page does not load anything.  The master page defines some common layout (and possibly code), and then you create child pages which only need to supply the content that is *not* defined in the master pages via the `ContentPlaceHolder`.

You then load the child pages, one at a time.